# WPF Avalon Wizard Binding Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using the [Avalon Wizard](http://avalonwizard.codeplex.com/) control, I have a lot of pages but only 2 are giving me problems so they will be all that is included:

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
  <w:Wizard Name="MyWizard"
            w:Designer.PageIndex="0"
            DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.Policy}">
    <w:WizardPage Header="Main Member"
                  MaxHeight="600"
                  AllowNext="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.CanContinue}"
                  Name="MainPage">
      <w:WizardPage Name="DeductionPage"
                    Header="Policy Details"
                    AllowNext="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.CanContinue}">
```

Now for the problem, the Allow Next of the Main Page is working perfectly, but then on the Deduction Page the next button is always available although the CanContinue property is set to false!

Note that `CanContinue` is only set to false when the second page is loaded.

```
    private bool canContinue;
public bool CanContinue
{
  get { return canContinue; }
  set
  {
    canContinue = value;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("CanContinue");
  }
}
```

--

UPDATE

I had a look at the output window and found the following exception:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=MainGrid'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.CanContinue; DataItem=null; target element is 'WizardPage' (Name='DeductionPage'); target property is 'AllowNext' (type 'Boolean')
```

This is happening on the page where my problem is, but why would it be a problem on the second page only? The first and second pages bind to the exact same thing and the first page works perfectly!

The problem is on all pages except the first page, all are children of the same Wizard on the same level.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there any binding errors or warnings in the debug output window? Also, if `CanContinue` is `false`, how do you move from the main page to the deduction page?

Comment: I do get a single binding error but that has nothing to do with this object. Sorry I should have clarified that CanContinue only becomes false when the second page is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code for `CanContinue`, this is a bit of a guess. However, in these cases, the culprit is usually due to a property not raising the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event. In your case, the property `CanContinue` must raise the INotifyPropertyChanged event.

Essentially, whenever the value of `CanContinue` needs to be evaluated, INotifyPropertyChanged must be raised. This will signal the UI that the value of `CanContinue` has changed and the UI must re-evaluate the bindings.

Often times, INotifyPropertyChanged is raised outside of the property itself. Such as when a method performs some work which results in the need to make sure the UI is still correctly bound. In your case, this may be when navigating between pages.

Comment: Sorry about that, included the code in my question. NotifyPropertyChanged was implemented. Still gives the same problem!

Comment: Check to see if the INotifyPropertyChanged needs to be called elsewhere, i.e., re-read the 3rd paragraph. This means that after some code executes, either raise the event by calling `NotifyPropertyChanged("CanContinue")` directly in some other method, or reset the value of `CanContinue` to force the event to be raised again.

Comment: If you note in my code I do the `NotifyPropertyChanged("CanContinue");` on the setter of the property, so whenever the value changes it will be called. This is the only time I need it to be called. Whenever validation completes on my object `CanContinue` is changed, when loading the second form it is set to false but the button stays enabled.